# How can i call two different functions of javascript on check and unckeck of same checkbox in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a javascript function `display()`, when a check box is checked and another function, `hide()` when that same check box is unchecked.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myonclickhandler(t) {
        if (t.checked) {
            display();
        }
        else {
            hide();
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" value="hi" onclick="myonclickhandler(this);">Text</input>
```

Comment: function check_value(item)
        {
            if(item.checked)
            {
                alert("checked");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("unchecked");
            }} i am using this function whenever i check or uncheck it it displays and alert with message unchecked

Comment: better to use onchange: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438068/perform-an-action-on-checkbox-cheched-or-unchecked-event-on-html-form