# Perform an action on checkbox checked or unchecked event on html form

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox on a form which is unchecked by default as usual. Now I want to perform two separated actions on the checked and unchecked state of this checkbox.

This is my checkbox:

```
<form>
    syn<input type="checkbox" name="checkfield" id="g01-01"  onchange="doalert(this.id)"/>
</form>
```

And this is my script:

```
function doalert(id){
  if(this.checked) {
     alert('checked');
  }else{
     alert('unchecked');
  }
}
```

It just alerts unchecked! What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what is `this` in your function?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

We can do this using JavaScript, no need of jQuery. Just pass the changed element and let JavaScript handle it.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    syn<input type="checkbox" name="checkfield" id="g01-01"  onchange="doalert(this)"/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function doalert(checkboxElem) {
  if (checkboxElem.checked) {
    alert ("hi");
  } else {
    alert ("bye");
  }
}
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9f66/162/)**

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and why your solution fixes it.

Comment: the only true answer was this one as I have to use the same ID for several items on the form. thnaks

Comment: @shekoufeh While this a great answer which solves your problem, it should also be known that all other answers are also true because you can't use the same `id` multiple times in a document. If you need to, you should change it to a class.

Comment: @ReeceKenney yes you are right but this is such a complicated form that I have to handle it in this way. thanks others for your nice answers.

Comment: It doesn't work under some circumstances. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59233171

Answer (score 4):

The problem is how you've attached the listener:

```
<input type="checkbox" ...  onchange="doalert(this.id)">
```

Inline listeners are effectively wrapped in a function which is called with the element as *this*. That function then calls the *doalert* function, but doesn't set its *this* so it will default to the global object (window in a browser).

Since the window object doesn't have a *checked* property, `this.checked` always resolves to false.

If you want *this* within *doalert* to be the element, attach the listener using *addEventListener*:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.querySelector('#g01-01');
  if (input) {   
    input.addEventListener('change', doalert, false);
  }
}
```

Or if you wish to use an inline listener:

```
<input type="checkbox" ...  onchange="doalert.call(this, this.id)">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<form>
    syn<input type="checkbox" name="checkfield" id="g01-01" />
</form>
```

js:

```
$('#g01-01').on('change',function(){
    var _val = $(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
    alert(_val);
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't liked, especially when they require a library not tagged or mentioned in the OP and don't either explain the issue or why your answer fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer doesn't always work.

(To read about the problem and circumstances, read this: [Defined function is "Not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32938879).)

So, you have 3 options:

1 (it has above-mentioned drawback)

```js
<input type="checkbox" onchange="doAlert(this)">

<script>
function doAlert(checkboxElem) {
    if (checkboxElem.checked) {
        alert ('hi');
    } else {
        alert ('bye');
    }
}
</script>
```

2 and 3

```js
<input type="checkbox" id="foo">

<script>
function doAlert() {
    var input = document.querySelector('#foo');

    // input.addEventListener('change', function() { ... });
    // or
    // input.onchange = function() { ... };
    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (input.checked) {
            alert ('hi');
        } else {
            alert ('bye');
        }
    });
}

doAlert();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `JQuery` change event?

```
$("#g01-01").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Then you can also remove `onchange="doalert(this.id)"` from your checkbox :)

**Edit:**

I don't know if you are using `JQuery`, but if you're not yet using it, you will need to put the following script in your page so you can use it:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a change event.

Comment: I have repeated this ID several times in the form for another purpose so I can not handle it in this way.

Comment: This answer is correct because you cannot use an `id` more than once in an `html` document. If you are using an `id` more than once, you should change it to a `class`. *"The most important aspect of the id attribute is that it must be absolutely unique. Unlike the class attribute, which may apply the same value to many elements in a page, an id that’s applied to an element must not match an id used anywhere else on the same page."* [HTML ID Attribute](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/id-html-attribute/)

Answer (score 1):

Given you use JQuery, you can do something like below :

### HTML

```
<form id="myform">
    syn<input type="checkbox" name="checkfield" id="g01-01"  onclick="doalert()"/>
</form>
```

### JS

```
function doalert() {
  if ($("#g01-01").is(":checked")) {
    alert ("hi");
  } else {
    alert ("bye");
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the onclick event is not accessible, since checkboxes checked via keyboard will not trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function copyAddr()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("addcopy").checked) 
        
        document.getElementById("permadd").value=document.getElementById("commadd").value;
        else
        document.getElementById("permadd").value="";
        
    }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="addcopy" onclick="copyAddr()">Communication address and Permanent address are same
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your code using developer tools, you will notice that `this` refers to the window object and not the input control. Consider using the passed in id to retrieve the input and check for `checked` value.

```
function doalert(id){
  if(document.getElementById(id).checked) {
    alert('checked');
  }else{
    alert('unchecked');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually won't help the OP to understand their problem.