# Defined function is "Not defined"

Tags: javascript, html

The following function is defined in the head tags of my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function(){

function greenTab(input){
    if ($input === 'second') {
        $('#green').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#2ndgreen').css({'display':'initial'});
    } else if ($input === 'first') {
        $('#2ndgreen').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#green').css({'display':'initial'});
    }
}   
});
</script>
```

And I call it in this fashion:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active" onclick="greenTab('first')"><a>1st Green</a></li>
        <li class="active" onclick="greenTab('second')"><a>2nd Green</a></li>                         
    </ul>
</div>
```

The issue: Firebug says the function is not defined.
Desired outcome: For the function to be defined.

Comment: `#green` and `#2ndgree` aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: Actually they are. But it's a lot of code and I didn't know if I should include it.

Answer (score 4):

## Why is it broken:

The `onclick` attribute expects functions to be exposed on global scope.

Because you have defined `greenTab` within the `ready` function, it is defined within the scope of that function, not on global scope, so it can't be found on the global scope.

## How to fix it:

Either:

1. Expose it globally. (Don't do this)
2. Add your event listeners through JS, not HTML (Probably do this)

Since you're using jQuery, you should add your event handlers like this:

```
$('some selector').click(function () {
    greenTab('first');
});
```

What some selector should be right now is `'.container ul li:nth-of-type(1)'`,
but I would suggest adding something to those elements to select on them better, eg:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active first-green"><a>1st Green</a></li>
        <li class="active second-green"><a>2nd Green</a></li>                         
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then your first selector should just be:

```
$('.first-green').click(function () {
    greenTab('first');
});
```

You will need to do the same for the second click handler as well.

Comment: I took them out of the ready function and it says they are still  not defined :(

Comment: Ok, I did it and now I don't get the not defined error, but the function doesn't work.