# jQuery on event isn't reading variable assigned to this

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The Problem**

I have a dynamically created checkbox input element.  I've assigned an isSelected boolean variable to the element.  I've assigned a select and deselect function to respective variables of the element as well.

These three variables work as expected except when I try to call it from an `on("click",function(){})` event.  They are all undefined in that context and I'm not sure why.

**Snippet - jQuery**

```
var input = $("<input type='checkbox' id='" + i + "_" + j + $(this).html() + "' />");
li.append(input); //li is a variable created elsewhere
input.isSelected = false;
input.select = function () {
    this.isSelected = true;
    console.log(this.isSelected); //true
}
input.deselect = function () {
    this.isSelected = false;
    console.log(this.isSelected); //false
}
input.select(); //logs true
input.on("click", function () {
    console.log(this.isSelected); //undefined
    if(this.isSelected){
        this.deselect(); //does not get called
    }else{
        this.select(); //does not get called
    }
})
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Inside your event handlers, `this` is not a jQuery. It's a native DOM Element. Also you can't just add a `.isSelected` onto your jquery instance...it will only apply to that instance. You probably want to use data, like `input.data('isSelected', false)`. And in your event handlers, you'd need to use `$(this).data('isSelected', false)`

Comment: @tyler_sells Can you add the html/css as well?

Comment: @David784 I get that for the isSelected variable, but is it reasonable to do this for the functions as well?

Comment: @Johnsackson This is just part of a jQuery plugin I'm working on.  There's not really any css or html associated with it at the moment.  It just creates a `ul` with `li`s that contain a checkbox and then adds that `ul` element after the element that the plugin was applied to

Comment: @TylerSells Anything you want to "attach" to the element so that you can get it back later (variables or functions), should probably go in the `.data()`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for more details.

Comment: Why don't you use the native `checked` property? Seems like an overly complicated set up for something very simple that is already available within the DOM already

Comment: @charlietfl I need some other things to happen when an item is checked as well.  This method allows me to call the select/deselect methods succinctly in a number of different ways and know that the actions will be 100% consistent with no duplicated code

Comment: But there are native events that you can listen to for changes on the checkbox. Really sounds like some serious over thinking going on here. If you need to use a jQuery custom event to trigger whatever you need but `checked` only has 2 possible states

Comment: @charlietfl so you're suggesting something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32438178/8469201

Comment: Not sure what your higher level issue is but basically yes

Comment: @charlietfl the higher level issue is that I have another checkbox that when checked/unchecked will cause all the other checkboxes to fire the same respective action, regardless of their current state (instead of just inverting it's current state).  I suppose the logic could be worked out to do it with the `on("change")` event, but this approach was where my head went first.

Comment: Yes ... is trivial to change checked state for multiple checkboxes within a change event handler. For example within a check-all checkbox can toggle all others doing something like `$('.otherCheckboxes').prop('checked', this.checked)`