# Selecting link from preselected links and go to choosen link once

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do something like; visit all the links only once, when all links have been visited delete the data of visited links and start from beginning to count visited links.

This code works great but sometimes same links coming consecutively.

```js
var urls=["http://randomemes.com/links/apotatoflewaround.html",
"youtube.com",
"yandex.com",
"google.com",

];
function goSomewhere() {
var e=Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);
window.location=urls[e],
urls.splice(e, 1)
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<input class="start" type="button" onClick="goSomewhere(); return ;" alt="Submit" width="800" height="100"value="»» Bring Memes ««">
```

Comment: You need `http://` for external links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, where are you going to save which links were visited? You can't just delete item from array because these values are not saved after you leave your page so when you get back to your page you will have full `urls` array. You could use `localStorage` to store your data. You could have an object for each link and inside it properties like `url` and `visited` to check if the page has been visited. However `localStorage` can't store javascript objects, just variables and JSON strings, but you can use `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` to work it out. Implementation could look like this (I wrote this in a hurry, it could probably be written shorter and better, but it should work and I wrote some explanations in comments):

```
// Store javascript object to localStorage
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

// Get javascript object from localStorage
Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key));
}

// Your URLs with default visited values
var urls = [
    { name: "somesite1", url: "http://somesite1.com", visited: false },
    { name: "somesite2", url: "http://somesite2.com", visited: false },
    { name: "somesite3", url: "http://somesite3.com", visited: false },
    { name: "somesite4", url: "http://somesite4.com", visited: false }
];

// If there's no urls object in localStorage, call setDefault method
if (!localStorage.getObject("urls")) {setDefault();}

// Check all link objects. If all are visited, return true, else return false
function checkVisited() {
    var counter = 0;
    var getUrls = localStorage.getObject("urls");
    for (var i = 0; i < getUrls.length; i++) {
        if (getUrls[i].visited) {counter++;}
    }
    return counter === getUrls.length;
}

// Set defaults values to localStorage
function setDefault() {
    localStorage.setObject("urls", urls);
}

// If all links are visited, set default values
// Then get random links until you find one
// that's not visited. When it's found, set it
// to visited in localStorage and redirect to it 
function goSomewhere() {
    if (checkVisited()) {setDefault();}
    var getUrls = localStorage.getObject("urls");
    var visited = true;
    while(visited) {
        var e = Math.floor(Math.random()*getUrls.length);
        if (!getUrls[e].visited) {
            visited = false;
            getUrls[e].visited = true;
            localStorage.setObject("urls", getUrls);
            window.location = getUrls[e].url;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. To see more info about `localStorage` check out MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Also for JSON: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: You are awesome! I was looking for something like that since 1 month.Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually i have one more question. I want to add a checkbox to my homepage. If it is checked than another preselected links set will be used.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438068/perform-an-action-on-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked-event-on-html-form

Comment: You can have three arrays, let's say `urls`, `urlsChecked`, `urlsUnchecked` and then look for onchange event on checkbox. When the event is fired you do something like `if (checkBox.checked) { urls = urlsChecked } else { urls = urlsUnchecked }`. You store values in the `urlsChecked ` and `urlsUnchecked` arrays and use `urls` just to pass them to function calls

Comment: I missed few things, for example you have to have at least two arrays in `localStorage` etc. You will still need to do your actions based on `onchange` event on checkbox so you need to look in that direction. You need to modify the code I posted a bit more, not just by adding what I wrote in the last comment. It's probably best if you open another question.